# How to make animation inside a StreamBuilder with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

In order to test the BloC design pattern, I started from the basic Flutter example.
The amination (scale type) inside a StreamBuilder does not work.

Here is the source code of the project: https://github.com/fabienbellanger/flutter_bloc_example.

The animation is only launched when the widget is loaded and not every time the counter changed.

[Edit] I would like that each time the "+" is tapped, the font size of the counter growth. It only work once time after loading the home page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzQ0J.gif)

**IncrementBloc**

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_bloc_example/src/blocs/bloc_provider.dart';

class IncrementBloc implements BlocBase {
  final int _counterInitial = 0;

  int counter;

  ///
  /// Stream to handle the counter
  ///
  StreamController<int> _counterController = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
  StreamSink<int> get _inUpdate => _counterController.sink;
  Stream<int> get outCounter => _counterController.stream;

  ///
  /// Stream to handle the action on the counter
  ///
  StreamController<String> _actionController = StreamController<String>();
  StreamSink<String> get updateCounter => _actionController.sink;

  ///
  /// Constructor
  ///
  IncrementBloc() {
    counter = _counterInitial;
    _actionController.stream.listen(_handleLogic);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _actionController.close();
    _counterController.close();
  }

  void _handleLogic(String data) {
    if (data == 'add') {
      counter = counter + 1;
    } else {
      if (counter == 0) {
        counter = 0;
      } else {
        counter = counter - 1;
      }
    }

    _inUpdate.add(counter);
  }
}
```

**CounterHomePage**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_example/src/blocs/bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_example/src/blocs/increment_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_example/src/blocs/navigation_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc_example/src/ui/pages/tabbar_page.dart';

///
/// CounterHome class
///
class CounterHome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CounterHomeState createState() => _CounterHomeState();
}

class _CounterHomeState extends State<CounterHome> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final IncrementBloc _incrementBloc = BlocProvider.of<IncrementBloc>(context);

    return Center(
      child: StreamBuilder<int>(
          stream: _incrementBloc.outCounter,
          initialData: _incrementBloc.counter,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                TextCounter(
                  counter: snapshot.data,
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColor: Colors.white70,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Go to TabBar Page',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
                        bloc: NavigationBloc(),
                        child: TabBarPage(),
                      );
                    }));
                  },
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class TextCounter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int counter;

  const TextCounter({Key key, this.counter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TextCounterState createState() => _TextCounterState();
}

class _TextCounterState extends State<TextCounter> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _animationSize;
  int counter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    counter = widget.counter;

    _animationController = new AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _animationController.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });

    _animationSize = new Tween(begin: 5.0, end: 70.0).animate(_animationController);

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(TextCounter oldWidget) {
    if (counter != widget.counter) {
      setState(() {
        counter = widget.counter;

        print('didUpdateWidget');
      });
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size = _animationSize?.value;

    return Text(
      counter.toString(),
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: size,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: post your animation code then

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added it.

Comment: Thank you, but I can't apply your solution.

Comment: did you run the widget I posted? what's the problem with applying it to your code?

Comment: When i run your widget, it works. But I couldn't apply it to my example :( The counter in blue is not animated after tapped increment button, but only when i  switch between BottomAppBar items.

Answer (score 0):

To do an animation for a transition in a streambuilder, it is pretty easy, you can simply use a widget called [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) :

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      child: _getMainWidget(snapshot, context),
    );
  },
);
}
```

Here we use an [AnimatedSwitcher](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedSwitcher-class.html) to animate a transition when the child of the AnimatedSwitcher change's, the default animation is a fade animmation, but you could easily specifiy your own animation by passing the widget a [TransitionBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransitionBuilder.html) as an argument

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still not work, even with AnimatedSwitcher :( I update the repo (https://github.com/fabienbellanger/flutter_bloc_example) with you want to see the code.

Comment: Hello Fabien i took a look at your code, i would suggest that you make sure of one thing : in your code you pass a key to the child of the AnimatedSwitcher : key: ValueKey<int>(snapshot.data), make sure this data is an int that changes every time, if the key is the same no animation will take place, how about passing the counter incremented value as the key ? that could make the trick ! good luck